# How to find xml is mapped with xsd schema in mule esb

Tags: xml, mule, xsd-validation

I have one `XML` file. The file is validate with `XSD` schema. When I debug my flow I am unable to get the output whether it is validate or not and I am not getting any error also.

Follows the file code:

```
<flow name="muledemowithxsdFlow">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\Mule ESB Docs"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="customer_validation.xsd" returnResult="false" name="Customer_schema_validation"
        doc:name="Schema Validation" />     
        <logger message="FILE OK: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Please help on this my `XML` is validate with `XSD` or not.

Comment: Just curious, why the first message processor is an `outbound-endpoint` instead of `inbound-endpoint` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see the error why it failed in the logs by configuring log4j.properties to include -

log4j.logger.org.mule.module.xml.filters.SchemaValidationFilter=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

if it is failing on dom to xml then use dataweave to convert and do check your input mimeType too.. it can be overridden in dataweave itself